# How can I refer to a user in a content type using CCK in Drupal 7.7

Tags: entities

In a content type I want to let the author select one or more of the site users. It's something like term reference field but I need to refer to a user instead. I can't find a suitable module for that although I can roughly remember that I did that before. I am using the latest drupal version 7.7.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references).